# backpack-for-laravel Custom list blade view, custumize columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to customize list.blade, but without any success so far. 
As I ca see in the file there is foreach loop that execute all the columns:

```
@foreach ($crud->columns as $column)
   <th>{{ $column['label'] }}</th>
@endforeach
```

what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
 @foreach ($crud->columns as $column)
   <th>{{ $column['id'] }}</th>
   <th>{{ $column['name'] }}</th>
   <th>{{ $column['price'] }}</th>
   ..........etc. 
 @endforeach
```

Of course this `{{ $column['id'] }}` dosen't work.

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Then shouldn't you loop through your `$column` as well? You could seperate out your `$column['id']` from your query.

Comment: What does this "$crud->columns" return ?